# WCF service - prevent generating <ExtensionData /> in response

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

I have contracts generated with svcutil.exe and the tool automatically generates ExtensionData fields.
The problem is, in the service xml response, the ExtensionData field is present
`<ExtensionData />`.

I have read something about IgnoreExtensionDataObject on ServiceBehaviorAttribute, but that didn't help.
How can I get rid of the element in response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This field is mainly used to resolve the inconsistency between the data contract versions defined by the server and the client. To do this, we need to add a property of type ExtensionDataObject on the client or server. In this way, data is not lost during server and client transmission.
Please refer to the below data contract on the server-side.

```
    [DataContract(Namespace ="ABCD")]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

**Client-side.**

```
    [DataContract(Namespace ="ABCD")]
    public class Product:IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }
        //[DataMember]
        //public string Description { get; set; }
        //[DataMember]
        //public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

When the client gets the value and configures this object, It will not lose the previous Description/Price field value. The ExtensionDataObject field will be used to maintain value.
Official document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/forward-compatible-data-contracts
Simply speaking, we don’t need to care about this field. Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: If I serialize the response in client with DataContractSerializer, the ExtensionData element is not present in the XML, however the service will be consumed by different program using Java and they have problems with this element in service response. Is there a way how to serialize it correctly in Java? They are generating proxy from .xsd file, where the ExtensionData element is not present.

Comment: IExtensibleDataObject is just an implementation in Dotnet framework. For the Java client, I don’t know if there are similar implementations. But if the data contract between the client-side and the server-side is correct, this should be no problem.